# How do I make the secondary fields for an external data column show in list forms

Tags: 2013, list-form, external-data-column

If I add an external data column to a SharePoint list and chooses to add one or more secondary fields, the secondary fields happily appear in list views but not in list forms. How do I make the secondary fields appear in the list forms as well?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint provisions field definitions for fields specified in the `SecondaryFieldWssNames` attribute as read-only fields (`ReadOnly="TRUE"`), and does **not** add any of the `ShowIn...Form` attributes to the field schema XML.

This effectively makes the secondary fields invisible in the list forms.

One can use PowerShell to add the necessary `ShowIn...Form` attributes to the field schema XML of a secondary field that should become visible in a list form.

Here's a sample code snippet illustrating the idea by using Office PnP commandlets:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$ctx = (Get-PnpConnection | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Context')
$list = Get-PnPList -Identity ExternalColumnTest

[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field]$projectAccountField = Get-PnPField -List $list -Identity 'Project_x003a__x0020_Account'
$ctx.Load($projectAccountField)  
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

[XML]$accountFieldSchema = $projectAccountField.SchemaXml
$accountFieldSchema.Field.setattribute('ShowInDisplayForm','TRUE')
$projectAccountField.SchemaXml = $accountFieldSchema.OuterXml
$projectAccountField.Update()

$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```